# How to get user info from a post made by the user in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a **User** model and a **Post** model. Now, only logged in users can create a new post. Now, when the post is submitted, I want to get the post info as well as the user info. If you see, I have used

`userId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }` to reference the **User** model.

Say, in the API tester Postman, what should I enter as the body?

```js
{
  "title": "abcd",
  "description": "efgh",
  //should userId be automatically generated or I have to enter here
}
```

I know slug is generated automatically but what about the user info? I'm getting confused here?
And how do I get user info from userId? (I have a route `/users/:id` though but don't know how to use it in this case)

**User Model**

```js
const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
}, { timestamps: true })
```

**Post Model**

```js
const postSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  description: { type: String, required: true },
  userId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
  slug: { type: String, slug: "title" }
}, { timestamps: true }
```

**authmiddleware.js**

```js
function generateToken(payload) {
    return jwt.sign(payload, "secret")
}

function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
    const token = req.headers.Authorization 

    if (!token) return res.json({ msg: "unauthorized"})

    jwt.verify(token,"secret",(err, decoded) => {
        if (err) return res.json({ error: "unuthorized" })
        req.user = decoded
        next()  
    })
}

module.exports = {generateToken, verifyToken }
```

**routes/posts.js**

```js
router.post("/new", authmiddleware.verifyToken, postControllers.newPost)
```

**postControllers/newPost.js**

```js
    newPost: (req, res) => {
        Post.create(req.body, (err, newPost) => {
            if (err) console.log(err)

            if (!newPost) {
                return res.json({ message: "No post found" })

            } else if (newPost) {
                return res.json({ post: newPost })
            }
        })
    }
```

When I checked in postman by entering this info as body(and sent token in headers)

```js
{
    "title": "My first post",
    "description": "My first post description"
}
```

I got this result:

```js
{
    "post": {
        "_id": "5e3028ded3e24b55e06baaf2",
        "title": "My first post",
        "description": "My first post description"
        "createdAt": "2020-01-28T12:28:14.331Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-01-28T12:28:14.331Z",
        "slug": "my-first-post",
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

But I also want to get the user info in this.

**Update**: So, I got the **userId** in the newly created **post** object.

I was doing this earlier:

```js
       newPost: (req, res) => {

        Post.create(req.body, req.user.userId, (err, newPost) => {
            if (err) console.log(err)

            if (!newPost) {
                return res.json({ message: "No post found" })
            } else if (newPost) {
                return res.json({ post: newPost })
            }
        })
    }
```

And got and error:

```js
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Parameter \"obj\" to Document() must be an object, got 5e2f365d41ff66569445eec2",
        "name": "ObjectParameterError"
    }
}
```

Then I did this I got the result:

```js
   newPost: (req, res) => {

        const data = {
            title: req.body.title,
            description: req.body.description,
            userId: req.user.userId
        }

        Post.create(data, (err, newPost) => {
            if (err) console.log(err)

            if (!newPost) {
                return res.json({ message: "No post found" })

            } else if (newPost) {
                return res.json({ post: newPost })
            }
        })
    }
```

It shouldn't be happening. No?

Comment: I believe you could user something as uuid package and generate user id at your user schema, when it is created

Comment: Do you have an auth middleware to get the logged in user?

Comment: Yes i have a auth middleware. In new post route I have added that middleware

Comment: Can you add that code to the question? Also it would be good if you can auth middleware code also.

Comment: added in the question @SuleymanSah

Comment: I already post an answer, can you try to apply it to your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the logged in user's id to the request in your auth middleware, and acccess the user id in your route.

Let's say you have a such auth middleware:

```js
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  let token;
  if (
    req.headers.authorization &&
    req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer")
  ) {
    token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
  }

  if (!token) return res.status(401).send("Access denied. No token provided.");

  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, "JWT_PRIVATE_KEY");
    req.user = decoded;
    next();
  } catch (ex) {
    res.status(400).send("Invalid token.");
  }
};
```

I assume you send the authorization token in the Authorization header in the format `Bearer TOKEN......`. If you send the token in a different header, you need to adjust code to read token accordingly.

Now when you apply this middleware to your route, you can read the user id from request,
and use it.

```js
const Post = require("../models/post");
const auth = require("../middleware/auth");

router.post("/posts", [auth], async (req, res) => {
  const result = await Post.create({
    title: req.body.title,
    description: req.body.description,
    user: req.user._id //comes from auth middleware
  });

  res.send(result);
});
```

For this to work, you need to include the user id in the token when you sign it.

```js
const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, "JWT_PRIVATE_KEY");
```

Comment: I'm getting a 500. Able to get the ```userId```  in ```req.user.userId``` though.


Error that I'm getting in Postman.


```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Parameter \"obj\" to Document() must be an object, got 5e2f365d41ff66569445eec2",
        "name": "ObjectParameterError"
    }
}
```

Comment: @hellraiser999 can you put your application code to github so that I can check it.

Comment: Okay. 
I got 200 but the result was the same. Only post info is showing.

Comment: @hellraiser999 do you include user's _id when you sign like this `jwt.sign({ _id: user._id },`

Comment: Oh, I got the ```userId``` in the new post object along with ```title```, ```description```, ```slug``` and all. Thanks!! Now how do I get that user info like ```username```, ```email``` here.

Comment: @hellraiser999 what do you send as payload here `return jwt.sign(payload, "secret")`? Also can you log req.user in the post route and say what does it display?

Comment: I sent ```jwt.sign({ userId: user._id }, "secret"))``` and I'm getting ```req.user``` as ```{ userId: '5e2f365d41ff66569445eec2', iat: 1580216403 }```

Comment: @hellraiser999  is the document saved successfully?

Comment: I got the userId. Now, how do I get the username, email etc of this particular user in this post object? So, that i can display somewhere ```this post was created by this user``` Yes the document has been saved successfully.

Comment: @hellraiser999 let's go step by step, does the post saved as you wanted to the collection?

Comment: Yes, it's been saved.